# How to allow a user to delete a comment only if they are the user that posted it with canEditRowAtIndexPath:

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to allow a user to delete a comment only if they are the user that posted it.

I'm using the canEditRowAtIndexPath: method and am trying the following. The delete is no longer showing after I include this conditional.

```
 if (userIdNumber == aNum) {
    return YES;
}

-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath   
{
    // Return YES if you want the specified item to be editable.    
    NSString *savedValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                        stringForKey:@"userId"];

    NSNumber *userIdNumber = [userId objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSNumber  *aNum = [NSNumber numberWithInteger: [savedValue integerValue]];

    NSLog(@"savedValue is %@",savedValue);

    NSLog(@"aNum is %@",aNum);

    NSLog(@"userIdNumber is %@",userIdNumber);

    if (userIdNumber == aNum) {
        return YES;
    }
    else {        
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `==` to compare two NSNumbers is a bad idea.  Do you know why?

Comment: (Hint:  Why is it a bad idea to use `==` to compare two NSStrings?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using == operator to compare two NSNumbers. Once compare two numbers by using `isEqualToNumber:` method like below.

```
if([userIdNumber isEqualToNumber:aNum]){
   return YES;
}else{
   return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As hinted by @Hot Licks, performing comparison of Objective-C objects requires more than just comparing their pointer values; you need to use the [`isEqual:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isEqual%3a) method:

```
return [userIdNumber isEqual:aNum];
```

(further more if the objects were `NSString` then you need to use [`[NSString isEqualToString:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/isEqualToString%3a)).